# Creating String through malloc and getchar()

Tags: c, string, malloc, stdin, getchar

So I'm trying to write a program that basically creates a string through memory allocation, reading character per character, but through only one input from the keyboard. I know there are multiple (better) ways to do it, but I wanted to do it through this particular way!
Here's the code:

```
int newstring (char** string)
{
printf("--------------In function newstring--------------\n");
int i = 0;
string = malloc ( sizeof (char) );
printf("Adress: %p\n", (void*)string);
if (string == NULL)
  return -1;

while ( 1 )
{
printf("Pre-scan\n");
*(string[i]) = getchar();
printf("After-scan\nstring[%d] = %c\n", i, *(string[i]));
i++;
if ( *(string[i-1]) == '\n')
  break;
printf("Reallocation to size %d\n", i+1);
string = realloc ( string, sizeof (char) * (i+1) );
if (string == NULL)
  return -1;
}

string[i-1] = '\0';
printf("--------------Exit function newstring--------------\n");
return;
}

int main()
{
char *string;
newstring ( &string );
printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

The problem is that the program always crashes midway before reading the 3rd character, here are the printfs that occurred:

```
Adress: 00AE1578
Pre-scan
 1st Input:  >>Hello
After-scan
string[0] = H
Reallocation to size 2
Pre-scan
After-scan
string[1] = e
Reallocation to size 3
Pre-scan
```

I've wondered if it's because of the buffer having some sort of limit but I find it hard to believe the limit is 2 characters (I've tried multiple inputs, always gets stuck before 3rd character). Also tried with "scanf ("%c", *(string[i]) )" to the same result.

Comment: You never call `free` - your program will leak memory and eventually halt because it will run out of memory.

Comment: @Dai I don't need to call free, because realloc already frees the previously allocated memory. If you're saying that i should call free in main, well, you're right but this program never reached main, so that wasn't the problem!

Comment: @ryyker I'm aware of that, I do it for clarity (if someone sees my code they'll know I was allocating memory for a "char" array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem starts with this:

```
string = malloc ( sizeof (char) );
```

Here `string` is a pointer to the actual pointer. You need to dereference it:

```
*string = malloc ( sizeof (char) );
```

Then the problem continues with

```
*(string[i]) = getchar();
```

You dereference the wrong thing, it should be

```
(*string)[i] = getchar();
```

Same with the other places where you use the wrong dereferencing.

And then

```
string[i-1] = '\0';
```

Here you don't dereference the pointer at all. Should be

```
(*string)[i-1] = '\0';
```

Finally, the [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an `int`. This is important when you check if the function failed or not by comparing the result to `EOF`. You do not do this at all.

Comment: Alright, I feel pretty dumb for making such an obvious mistake!
I don't understand what you mean with the getchar part though, why do I need to search for an EOF if I'm scanning from the keyboard? Shouldn't I be seraching for an '\n'? I do realize EOF also works for the end of the input stream, but in this particular case i'ts impossible to reach EOF without first reaching the newline character, no?

Comment: @CarlosPinto The symbolic constant `EOF` is an `int`. There is a possibility that `EOF != (char) EOF`. And regarding the newline what if the input is redirected from a file without a newline before the end of the file?